# A trigonometry application involving law of cosines?

Tags: trigonometry

Suppose you and your friend are on a yacht and both leave the dock at 12:00 hours. Suppose your yacht can go at $40$  km/hr. Unfortunately, just before you left, your friend sneaked off the yacht. at $12:30$ hours your friend steals a faster boat from the same dock which goes at $50$ km/hr and leaves from the same dock in a direction which is an angle $\alpha$ counterclockwise from you. Write a function $F(t)$ that gives you the distance from your yacht to your friend's boat at time $t$ (where $t$ is measured in hours after 12:00 hours).

To find $F(t)$ I have used law of cosines. Here is my atempt:

[image]

IS this a correct set up for the function  I am looking for?

Comment: You forgot to count on the speeds.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea but you forgot to multiply $t$ by the speed each boat is going and you forgot to note that $t$ is measured starting at 12:00.
Thus your equation should be
$$f(t)=\sqrt{(50t-25)^2 + (40t)^2 - 2(50t-25)(40t)\cos(\alpha)}$$
assuming $t>=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: why do you substract $25$ ?

Comment: IT doesnt make sense to assume $t \geq 1/2$

Comment: If $t<1/2$, then it will be before 12:30 and your friend's boat won't have left yet. You subtract 25 because the friend's boat has moved 50(t-0.5)=50t-25 km.